# Is it useful to loop an hmac hash?

Tags: php, security, hmac

I need to store a password in a database, and I used to store an sha1 hash of a salted password alongside a random salt, which was looped, like so:

```
$salt = sha1(microtime().mt_rand());
for ($i=0; $i < 4000; $i++) {
    $password = sha1($password.$salt);
}
```

(In my example, `$password` and `$salt` were stored inside the db).

I recently discovered the `hash_hmac()` function, which apparently is a much more secure function than a simple SHA1 hash. I plan on using it with the same pattern (the salt being the secret key), but I was wondering if it was worthwile to loop it like in my previous example. If anyone could give me some insight, that'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

What you're doing here is known as *[key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)* and it multiplies the time an attacker has to take to check each candidate password against a hash.  In your example, it increases the time by 4000x.  The specific threat you are protecting against here is when an attacker gets hold of your hashes (such as what happened with LinkedIn, Last.fm and eHarmony recently) and can devote as much CPU power as he can afford to cracking them.

Rather than rolling your own, if this is anything other than a research project, you should use a well-known and publicly tested function like [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [`PBKDF2()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [`scrypt()`](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html).

The number in that loop should be much higher than 4000 and since your attacker will be using a C loop rather than a PHP loop, you won't be able to do as many in a reasonable time as he will.  Even in a PHP loop, I can do 500,000 in 0.3 seconds.  The above hashing algorithms solve this problem since they will be implemented in C.  ([Not all of them may be available in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149554/are-there-any-php-implementations-of-scrypt).)  It seems `bcrypt` is in 5.3 but it's called `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`.  [Details on how to use it are on the crypt() page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

---

`hash_hmac()` is not a *more secure* hashing algorithm but rather is used for a different purpose.  See [the end of Thomas' answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10901/openssl-digest-vs-hash-vs-hash-hmac-difference-between-salt-hmac).  Algorithms like `MD5` and the `SHA` family are general purpose hashing algorithms that are normally used as part of a more specific algorithm for a particular purpose.  For instance, some of the above password hashing algorithms use general purpose hashing algorithms many times.  `has_hmac()` asks you which general purpose hashing algorithm you would like to use.